# Insert chinese characters to nclob column in plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql, nclob

I have a procedure and the text has chinese characters and has to be inserted into a table

```
create or replace procedure nclob_Test (text1 nclob)
as
begin
insert into abc123(nclobtext)
values (text1);
end;
/
```

**TABLE**

CREATE TABLE RESULTS.ABC123
(
NCLOBTEXT  NCLOB
);

```
DECLARE
    var_TEXT1   nclob;
BEGIN
    var_TEXT1 := '这不是杂志';
    RESULTS.NCLOB_TEST (TEXT1 => TO_NCLOB(var_TEXT1));

    COMMIT;
END;
```

The column is inserted as ¿¿¿¿¿

This input parameter is passed in from UI and they are unable to pass it as N'这不是杂志'

Is there a way that I can do this in the procedure.

Comment: If you have to end up with an NCLOB, why are you using VARCHAR2 rather than NVARCHAR2? What are your database and national character sets? Also you can use the `dump()` function to verify exactly what has been stored; it may be that your client can't display the value, rather than it being wrong. [It basically works](https://dbfiddle.uk/sf0kZsEt).

Comment: I updated my code to nclob and it still inserting inverted question marks

Comment: Again, is it inserting them like that, or are you just seeing them because your client can't display the actual characters properly? Check your client/IDE/application and OS character set - they all need to be set to something that understands those (e.g. UTF8). If you're querying through SQL\*Plus then check your NLS_LANG setting.

Comment: I am using sql developer and if I insert directly using N' I can see the chinese characters

Comment: As Alex suggested: Use dump to see what is stored in the NCLOB string. Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/bSUprlTQ

Comment: The below is the dump values
nvarchar value - ¿¿¿¿¿
dump nvarchar- Typ=1 Len=10: 0,191,0,191,0,191,0,191,0,191

varchar  value - ¿¿¿¿¿
dump varchar - Typ=1 Len=5: 191,191,191,191,191